# websocket await close vs await wait_closed

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm using the websockets package on python and I'm opening a connection as a client,
but **NOT** in a block context like this:

```
async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket:
    ...
```

I'm opening the connection like this:

```
websocket = await websockets.connect(uri)
```

The thing is that I don't under stand what is the right way to close the connection.
The [document](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html#) explains here about `await close()` and `await wait_closed()`, but I don't understand the differences.

Does both are fine?
Should I use both?
If someone would share his experience it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wait_closed`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html#websockets.client.WebSocketClientProtocol.wait_closed) is used to handle connection termination. And the [`close`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html#websockets.client.WebSocketClientProtocol.close) requests a connection termination and waits until the connection is closed.
So if you want to close the connection you should use only `await close()`.

Comment: I yet not sure I understand. close() request for a connection termination and waits till it's done. But what the wait_close() does? What it means to handle a connection termination? Maybe an example when to use wait_close()

Comment: For example, a connection can be terminated when something goes wrong on another side of the connection. Also can be terminated when the internet connection is lost at one of the sides, etc.

Comment: According your example, if we have issues with connection, why not just call close()? What is the benefit of calling wait_close() instead?

Comment: As we don't know when errors can occur or be terminated on another side of the connection, with `close()`, we close the connection from the client-side, and the `wait_close()` can be used in a concurrent task to handle the unexpected connection termination from another side of the connection or use in server-side to handle the connection close and clear session data for example.